# <fb:request-form> show as not correct size

Tags: css, facebook, fbml

my `<fb:request-form>` show incorrect size (width).

here is my code:

```
<fb:serverFbml style="width:600px;">
    <script type="text/fbml">
      <fb:fbml>
          <fb:request-form
                    action="<?= BASE_URL; ?>/pages/eid/inc/_send_card.php?ctid=<?= $card_type_id; ?>"
                    target="_top"
                    method="POST"
                    invite="true"
                    type="Muslimsquare Gift Card"
                    content="<?= $name; ?> ได้ส่งของขวัญเนื่องในวันอีดิ้ลฟิตรี่ให้กับคุณ โดยหวังว่าคุณจะตอบรับของขวัญของเขา คลิกปุ่ม Accept เพื่อตอบรับของขวัญจาก <?= $name; ?> และส่งของขวัญให้คนอื่นๆต่อไป <fb:req-choice url='http://www.muslimsquare.com/applications/pages/eid/acp_gift.php?uid=<?= $uid; ?>' label='Accept' />"
                    <fb:multi-friend-selector
                    showborder="false"
                    actiontext="เลือกเพื่อนที่คุณต้องการส่งของขวัญให้">
        </fb:request-form>
      </fb:fbml>
    </script>
    </fb:serverFbml>
```

But when it show in iframe application. it is about `width:964px;` and my iframe application display some stupid scrollbar like :

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `<fb:serverFbml width= "755">` NOT the `style="width: 755px"` attribute.

See [my blog post](http://www.berecursive.com/2010/facebook/facebook-fbmultifriendselector-in-iframe) about this.